# ASPX page to render image suddenly not working in Firefox. Works in Chrome/IE

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have an ASPX page used to pull an image from the database and write the bytes. I have used this method in the past and it has worked just fine. The basic rendering code is as follows:

GetBannerImage.aspx.cs

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", Convert.ToString(banner.Image.Length));
    Response.BinaryWrite(banner.Image);
    Response.End();
```

On another page, Default.aspx, I spit out some HTML to an ASP literal, as follows:

```
    this.ltlImage.Text = "<img src='" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/GetBannerImage.aspx?banner_id=" + banner.Id) + "' />";
```

I have a break point in the Page_Load event of my GetBannerImage.aspx page.

When I view the page source (in Firefox) of Default.aspx, I can click on the src attribute of the image which links to my GetBannerImage.aspx page, hits the breakpoint, and spits out the image. However, there is no image rendered to the screen on the Default.aspx page, and the break point isn't being hit when Default.aspx loads.

In IE and Chrome I am not having this issue - the image loads fine. I am confident that this is not an issue with my rendering code, and I am positive that the src tag is valid. I do not recall updating Firefox recently, but it appears that this is a new issue. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try to disable the FireFox cache. I had something like this happen. I want to say it had something to with the cache. I just add the Web Developer extension and  disable the entire cache with it.

Comment: Check all resources FireFox loads just yo make sure its not hitting a different URL. Also, you can try it in FireFox private mode (usually `CTRL + P`) to use an absolutely clean environment

Comment: @Xm7X Disabling the cache did not seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Diego It is hitting the correct URL. I will try using private mode, although I'm skeptical it will make a difference and even it does, this is not something we can expect our customers to do when using the application.

Comment: The private mode its not as a solution but just for testing proposes. If you can see the right URL being hit, then you can try to put a breakpoint in `BeginRequest` method in the `Global.asax`

Comment: You can try to disable all your FireFox extensions. Maybe something in there is blocking the image.

Comment: Maybe a security setting

Comment: @Xm7X I tried toggling some of my extensions on and off and found the culprit. The image was being loaded properly when I disabled Ad-Block Plus. Thanks for the suggestion. I will write a solution post. Is there a proper way to give you the credit for it?

Comment: @Ryan The usual way is to ask the commenter (in this case Xm7X) to write their comment as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to disable all your FireFox extensions. Maybe something in there is blocking the image.

Answer (score 2):

As @Xm7x suggested, I tried toggling some of my extensions on and off and found out that Ad-Block Plus was preventing the image from rendering. Disabling the extension seemed to allow the image to render fine.